# "Process is not defined" with react-chartjs-2 CDN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, cdn, react-chartjs

I am using the React CDN specifically for one component on a dashboard page. I would like to use ChartJS in the component and noticed that it has a CDN as well `react-chartjs-2`. However, when I add the script I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at react-chartjs-2.js:80
    at react-chartjs-2.js:4
    at react-chartjs-2.js:5
```

On line 80 is:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  validateFormat = function validateFormat(format) {
    if (format === undefined) {
      throw new Error('invariant requires an error message argument');
    }
  };
}
```

Lines 1 - 5:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports, require('react'), require('chart.js')) :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports', 'react', 'chart.js'], factory) :
    (factory((global.ReactChartjs2 = {}),global.React,global.Chart));
}(this, (function (exports,React,Chart) { 'use strict';
```

In the HTML the scripts are thus:

```
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-chartjs-2/2.9.0/react-chartjs-2.js"></script>
```

I'm really not finding a lot of information about the CDN anywhere so I'm wondering if these CDNs do not work together or if there's something I'm missing.

Any help in getting this moving would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The library, like most React components, does not support the browser natively. It assumes it's in a build tool environment (i.e. Node.js) so it thinks there's already a global `process` object. This is an oversight by the developers, but your use case is relatively uncommon, so they don't test it.

You need to use a build tool like Webpack, Rollup, or Parcel to be able to use that library.

PS: to reduce bundle size you should use `.min.js` CDNs instead of `.js`, i.e. have the URL be `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-chartjs-2/2.9.0/react-chartjs-2.min.js`.